# Bluetooth antenna went bad - can I just get a dongle?

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth, headphones

I have a late-2010 Mac Mini (maxed out at Mac OS X 10.7.5) with 2 bluetooth devices (keyboard and headphones).  I've had intermittent issues with bluetooth connectivity, but this past weekend, the connection went out while I was watching a movie and I could not get either device to reconnect.  So I think that the antenna has just gone bad.  I discovered that I can confirm this diagnosis using "Bluetooth Explorer" (part of XCode).  I installed that remotely and intend to test it out when I get home.

Assuming that I confirm that the antenna has just gone bad (or even if it hasn't), can I just purchase a bluetooth dongle, such as the "Kinivo BTD-300 Bluetooth 3.0 USB adapter" and expect to be able to circumvent the issue or will the built-in & faulty bluetooth capability interfere with the use of the dongle?

Comment: Let me get that, your BT headset is not working but your Bluetooth keyboard is!

Comment: Neither the keyboard nor the headset work when the problem occurs. Sorry for any ambiguity. I rarely use the keyboard. I confirmed the other night that the headset works fine when I pair it with my iPad, so it's not the headset. No bluetooth device currently works with my computer, hence my question stated above: "can I just purchase a bluetooth dongle ... and expect to be able to circumvent the issue?"

Comment: that is a yes to USB- BT dongle.

Comment: OK, well I ordered a BT-dongle. I checked with Apple's tech support first and they said it should work. I read some articles that warn about jumping through hoops to get the computer to prefer the dongle over the built-in BT capabilities. We'll see how it goes. One note: I wondered if I could get a dongle that provides BT 4.0 capabilities, but my mini, maxed out at 10.7.5, can't even run the BeaconOSX app, so I decided not to splurge on a BT 4.0 dongle.

Comment: FYI I deleted my answer since it was not correct.

Comment: For all I know, it still could be correct and whatever is happening is affecting whichever BT antenna is currently being utilized. I just don't know for sure yet what the source of the issue is. My hunch was that it was the antenna - perhaps damaged when I installed a new hard drive awhile back, but it could just as easily be a software issue.  Though it doesn't seem to be the anyconnect security agent since it has happened again since I uninstalled that.